# pytest how to mock functions from another module

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I have a directory structure:

```
├── src
│   └── chkfixt
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── config.py
│       ├── main.py
│       └── util.py
└── tests
    └── test_chkfixt.py
```

Files have contents as:

###### config.py

```
APP_NAME = 'not_mocked'
```

###### util.py

```
from pathlib import Path

from chkfixt.config import APP_NAME


def get_app_dir() -> str:
    return Path(APP_NAME)


def get_metadata_pickle_file_path() -> Path:
    app_dir = get_app_dir()
    config_path = Path(app_dir) / "metadata.pkl"
    return config_path


def save_metadata_to_pickle_file():
    pickle_file = get_metadata_pickle_file_path()
    print(f"saved to {pickle_file}")
```

###### main.py

```
from chkfixt.util import (get_metadata_pickle_file_path,
                          save_metadata_to_pickle_file)

print(f"pkl_file = {get_metadata_pickle_file_path()}")
save_metadata_to_pickle_file()
```

If I run main.py output is like this:

```
(deleteme) user@server:~/tmp/chkfixt$ python src/chkfixt/main.py
pkl_file = not_mocked/metadata.pkl
saved to not_mocked/metadata.pkl
```

In pytest, I need a different pkl_file for each test, so I have to mock `get_metadata_pickle_file_path()` function.

My first attempt in `test_chkfixt.py` was (ignore monkeypatch repetition for now) like this:

```
import pytest
from rich import print

from chkfixt.main import (get_metadata_pickle_file_path,
                          save_metadata_to_pickle_file)


@pytest.fixture
def mocked_pkl_file(tmp_path):
    return tmp_path / "metadata.pkl"


def test_mocked_get_pkl(mocked_pkl_file, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(
        "chkfixt.main",
        "get_metadata_pickle_file_path",
        lambda: str(mocked_pkl_file),
    )
    print(get_metadata_pickle_file_path())


def test_mocked_save_pkl(mocked_pkl_file, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(
        "chkfixt.main",
        "get_metadata_pickle_file_path",
        lambda: str(mocked_pkl_file),
    )
    print(save_metadata_to_pickle_file())
```

But that produced errors:

```
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_mocked_get_pkl ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

mocked_pkl_file = PosixPath('/tmp/pytest-of-user/pytest-89/test_mocked_get_pkl0/metadata.pkl'), monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7ff900732ec0>

    def test_mocked_get_pkl(mocked_pkl_file, monkeypatch):
>       monkeypatch.setattr(
            "chkfixt.main",
            "get_metadata_pickle_file_path",
            lambda: str(mocked_pkl_file),
        )
E       AttributeError: 'chkfixt.main' has no attribute 'get_metadata_pickle_file_path'

tests/test_chkfixt.py:14: AttributeError
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_mocked_save_pkl _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

mocked_pkl_file = PosixPath('/tmp/pytest-of-user/pytest-89/test_mocked_save_pkl0/metadata.pkl'), monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7ff9007b5db0>

    def test_mocked_save_pkl(mocked_pkl_file, monkeypatch):
>       monkeypatch.setattr(
            "chkfixt.main",
            "get_metadata_pickle_file_path",
            lambda: str(mocked_pkl_file),
        )
E       AttributeError: 'chkfixt.main' has no attribute 'get_metadata_pickle_file_path'

tests/test_chkfixt.py:23: AttributeError
```

Here, I am confused with error that is saying `'chkfixt.main' has no attribute 'get_metadata_pickle_file_path'`.

If I change test functions like this (merged `"chkfixt.main", "get_metadata_pickle_file_path"` to `"chkfixt.main.get_metadata_pickle_file_path"`):

```
def test_mocked_get_pkl(mocked_pkl_file, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(
        "chkfixt.main.get_metadata_pickle_file_path",
        lambda: str(mocked_pkl_file),
    )
    print(get_metadata_pickle_file_path())


def test_mocked_save_pkl(mocked_pkl_file, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(
        "chkfixt.main.get_metadata_pickle_file_path",
        lambda: str(mocked_pkl_file),
    )
    print(save_metadata_to_pickle_file())
```

I am not getting errors anymore, but test output is still `not_mocked/metadata.pkl`:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/user/tmp/chkfixt
plugins: forked-1.4.0, cov-3.0.0, black-0.3.12, mypy-0.9.1, xdist-2.5.0, flake8-1.1.1
collecting ... pkl_file = not_mocked/metadata.pkl
saved to not_mocked/metadata.pkl
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

tests/test_chkfixt.py not_mocked/metadata.pkl
.saved to not_mocked/metadata.pkl
None
.
```

As output shows, both paths are `not_mocked/metadata.pkl`, but I expect them to be from `mocked_pkl_file` fixture.

How to mock `main.py` `get_metadata_pickle_file_path` and `save_metadata_to_pickle_file` functions to use path from `mocked_pkl_file` fixture.

Answer (score 0):

You should be patching the imported objects, not strings. Also, import the module, don't use `from .. import ...` statements, so that pytest is able to access the module it is patching:

```py
import chkfixt.main

def test_mocked_save_pkl(mocked_pkl_file, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(
       chkfixt.main,
       "get_metadata_pickle_file_path",
       lambda: str(mocked_pkl_file),
    )
```

See the [how to monkey patch docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html) for more examples.

Comment: I saw the document from the link you have provided, but it is not working.
Can you please provide a full test_chkfixt.py?

Comment: see my update. if it's not working, can you be specific about exactly what happens?